# alert() and confirm() not showing on parent of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code:

**page1.php:**

```
<html>...source...<iframe src="page2.php"/> ...more source...</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<html><script> function myfunc(){window.confirm('....') ... more source}</script></html>
```

Whenever I'm dealing with `page2`, it displays the confirm (alert) window as it should, however whenever opening it from page1 and it displaying in the iframe, it doesn't show up. I tried with `window.parent.window.confirm/alert` as well, but no dice, so I suppose I'm missing something else here. Therefore my question is:
how to make sure calling a local JS function from our iframed page would show up on the parent one as well?

Comment: How and where are you calling the function? Are you trying to use the function in page1?

Comment: Do you actually need to reference `window` twice or can you just do `window.parent.confirm`?...

Comment: @Guffa it's a onclick event - I'm calling it whilst having page2 loaded in page1 as an iframe source.

Comment: Is the onclick event being triggered from page1 or page2?

Comment: @War10ck to be honest, dunno whether I need two references to window (although it would make sence to call once the current window, then the parent and its window, but I'm not a big js pro so I might be wrong), but I tried with window.parent.conrifm() too and the result wasn't really that much different..

Comment: @skshoyeb it's being triggered from page2, being an iframe in page1. Meaning I have both the function and element calling the on-click event handler, thus the function both within page2.

Comment: You're having it called while loading? Are you sure the function is even being called then? If you place a breakpoint inside the function does it hit that breakpoint? (or if you do `console.log('test');` inside the function, do you see it output to the console?)

Comment: @DavidSherret quite frankly haven't tried neither breakpoint, not dumping a log to see that.. It's worth the shot I guess :)

Comment: Yup, apparently the onclick event handler doesn't work whilst in an iframe. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Your not showing how your binding the onclick event handler, so no...

Comment: its working for me.. can i see how u r triggering the function?

Comment: I'm not binding anything - I just have an element (in this case an image) with an onclick event handler. It works if it's used from within page2 itself directly. If done from page1, whilst page2 is opened as iframe source, the call doesn't occur (actually I'm a bit surprised by that).. This is literally an oversimplified version of my source, not adding any of the non-relevant source. Should I do anything on page1 if I want to use my local for page2 onclick event handlers and functions? thx

Comment: Are you getting an error when calling the function? You're probably calling it before page2 has finished loading.

Comment: nope, nothing. I added a console.log before the confirm and I don't get it dumped in the console either - that's why I think I'm not calling the function at all and my assumption that probably the event handler doesn't work whilst in an iframe..

Comment: what the.. I just noticed I can't do anything with my iframe elements, including selecting the text (which probably is the key to the tent here...

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint where `myfunc` is actually called? Maybe that's not being run either...

Comment: may be u r not actually clicking the iframe.. is there any layer above that or some z-index issue, that is preventing u to click on it?

Comment: thx guys - it was exactly a z-index issue in one of my div containers (see below). Thx again! I was sure it was some dumb mistake along the way... Btw for the protocol, the call of the confirm/alert func's works now even without the window.parent.window.confirm directive ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

damn, I feel dumb as heck - not being able to even select my textual elements made me realize I had a z-index on one of the divs the iframe is housed in @ -1, which made it unselectable. Once fixing that the issue was resolved. Thx to everybody for their comments and help!

Comment: It happens to all of us. Next time try to utilize debugging so you can get to the source of the problem quicker. Also, right clicking elements and clicking "Inspect element" can help discover z-index issues.